# Protractor Cucumber- Unable to match spec file pattern (listing 2 features)

Tags: javascript, selenium, cucumber, protractor

I'm trying to get 2 different cucumber features to run

In my protractor.conf.js file, I've added:

`specs: ['add.feature', 'delete.feature']`

but when I run the tests I get `pattern add.feature,delete/feature did not match any files`

I am able to run these features individually ie. `specs:['add.feature']`

What am I missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you were not properly closing and opening single quotes and had something like:

```
specs: ['add.feature,delete/feature'],
```

Instead, make sure to properly define the specs as an array of strings:

```
specs: ['add.feature', 'delete.feature'],
```